# spresenseハイレゾ録音について

Tags: spresense

Spresenseにてハイレゾの録音をしたいと考えております。

・192kHz/24bitでの録音で80kHzまでの周波数を取得したい

物品構成
・Spresenseメインボード＋拡張ボード
・MEMSアナログマイク（↓の商品）
https://www.switch-science.com/products/5462

スケッチ例のrecorder.wavを一部変更したのですが
SDカードに出力されるsound.wavが上手くファイル出力されません（容量1KB）
スケッチを変更せず動作させるとsound.wavは正常に出力されます
（容量1.8MB）

recorder.wav内のtheAudio->setRecorderModeを
バッファサイズをドキュメント通り500kbでspresenseメモリ1028kbにしたのですが、やはりハイレゾではうまく出力されず、考えられる原因をご教示いただけますと幸いです。

変更点

```c
/*static const uint32_t recoding_sampling_rate = 48000;*/
static const uint32_t recoding_sampling_rate = 192000;
```

```c
/*static const uint8_t recoding_bit_length = 16;*/
static const uint8_t recoding_bit_length = 24;
```

```c
theAudio->initRecorder(AS_CODECTYPE_WAV,
"/mnt/sd0/BIN",
/*recoding_sampling_rate,
recoding_bit_length,
recoding_cannel_number*/
AS_SAMPLINGRATE_192000,
AS_BITLENGTH_24,
AS_CHANNEL_MONO);
puts("Init Recorder!");
```

```c
/*theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC);*/
theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC,(500*1028));　// ←変更してもダメでした
```

Answer (score 1):

> SDカードに出力されるsound.wavが上手くファイル出力されません（容量1KB）

の情報が少なく何か起こっているのかわからないですが、エラーなどが出ているのであれば、
そちらを添付してもらうと何かわかるかもしれません。

ただ、1点、ハイレゾで録音する場合、以下の一行の追加必要です。

theAudio->begin(audio_attention_cb);

の後ろに

/* Set clock mode to Hi-Res */
theAudio->setRenderingClockMode(AS_CLKMODE_HIRES);

がないと、
エラーコード：0x14

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_as_ecode_command_param_sampling_rate

が発生し、正しく録音ができないようです。

また、それでも録音に失敗する場合は、SDカードを以下のSDカードフォーマッターでフォーマットしてみると解決する可能性があります。

https://www.sdcard.org/ja/downloads-2/formatter-2/

Comment: 基本的にSDカードの速度が律速になるので、安心できるメーカの速度クラスも10のものを使う方が良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました！

/* Set clock mode to Hi-Res */
theAudio->setRenderingClockMode(AS_CLKMODE_HIRES);

こちらの行が抜けていたため、ハイレゾモードで動作しなかったことが原因でした。